# Find average value of binary tree c++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-tree

So I'm trying to write a recursive function to return the average value of a binary tree of values in c++. Here's what I have, that doesn't work:

```
double avg(bNode* root)
{
    if(!root) return 0;
    int sum = avg(root->left) + avg(root->right) + root->value;
    if(root->left && root->right) return sum/3;
    else if(!root->left && !root->right) return sum;
    else return sum/2;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried drawing a simple tree on paper and trying your algorithm out by hand?

Comment: Is it show any error? can you post the result you had

Comment: consider the tree where the root node has the value 1, left has 2 and left->left has 3. One can easily verify that the average is 2. Your function however will yield 1.75. I dont think this is easily done recursive, consider using an accumulator.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simply example that should illustrate why what you're calculating is not an average:

```
    10
   /  \
  4    12 
         \
          20
```

At the '12' node the average will be `(12 + 20) / 2 = 16`.

Then at the `10` node the average will be `(4 + 10 + 16) / 3 = 10`.

However, the average is really `11.5`.

The issue is that averages of averages of averages doesn't equal one big correct average.  At each level you have to multiply the average by the number of nodes that were used to calculate it (i.e. sum) before using it in the next average calculation.

An easier way to do this is probably to calculate the sum and then divide by the number of nodes in the tree.

Some **pseudo-code** for one technique to do this would be:

```
class accumulator
{
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // implement the obvious operator+
};

accumulator avg(bNode* root)
{
    if(!root) return <empty accumulator>
    return <recursive children> + <self>;
}

int main()
{
    accumulator acc = avg(root);
    // ..calculate average..
}
```